# displaying name and age in same label via JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been trying to fetch data from JSON to the label of collection view cell. I need to display name and age within a same label and city and distance within a same label just like this.

[image].

I have already done fetching data but by taking different labels for all the four of them. How can i do the same thing in two different labels.

Comment: use stringWithFormat like `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  ( %@ )", @"dave123", @"50"]`

Comment: Really?   A question on how to use `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`?

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere guys..

Comment: thanks for being nice to me @emotality

Comment: and don't mind being asked some sort of silly questions by anyone @Droppy

Comment: The problem is not the silliness of the question but the laid back attitude. What you are asking is obviously on the string reference. If you bother to read documentation of the language you are trying to learn of course.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by following:

```
self.LabelName.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ , %@",name,age];
```

Comment: name and age is what you've parsed from json @priya sharma

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *json = @{@"name":@"dave123", @"age":@"50"};
NSString *name = json[@"name"];
NSString *age = json[@"age"];

UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 40)];
[nameLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", name, age]];
[self.view addSubview:nameLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use stringWithFormat:

```
str1 = @"test1";
str2 = @"test2";
yourLabel =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"str1:%@ and str2:%@", str1, str2];
```

yourLabel -> str1:test1 and str2:test2